# Bootstrap 5 dropdown only active above parent element

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu within a div. Clicking the icon causes the dropdown to appear, but only those dropdown options that overlap the parent div are able to be hovered/clicked.

In the screenshot below, the 'Action' option works correctly (as it overlaps the blue parent div), but hovering over either 'Another action' or 'Something else here' does nothing and clicking them just closes the menu.

[image: Illustration of dropdown menu]

I suspect the issue is the `boundary` option described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#options). I don't fully understand either the Bootstrap or the Popper documentation for this, but I assume I need to set that value to some sort of container div (or even `body`).

The Bootstrap documentation says that can only be done via javascript (not via data attributes), so I added this code:

```
var dropdownElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle'))
    var dropdownList = dropdownElementList.map(function (dropdownToggleEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownToggleEl, {
        boundary: document.querySelector('#planContainer')
      })
    })
```

However, this does not appear to make any difference. It also makes no difference if I set `boundary: document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]`.

Any suggestions for where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this website where we can see this in action or add a `minimal reproducible example` by providing enough code for this in a Stack snippet? You can use this in the html of your snippet: `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Hi, unfortunenately the code is not currently live on the web, but I have made a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvjqwzno/1/

Annoyingly, it works perfectly in the JSFiddle and I cannot figure out what the difference is. The issue is definitely the parent div, as if I make the parent div larger, or offset the dropdown so that it stays within the div, I do not get the issue.

Comment: We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or to see your code.

Comment: @Rob -- are you going to add a reproducible example?

Comment: @Zim Hi, sorry I've been completely unable to reproduce the issue in JSFiddle. Weirdly, the issue in my development code spontaneously disappeared, then reappeared again some time later and I haven't been able to figure out why. In the end, I redesigned the toolbar entirely to eliminate this issue.

I will probably delete this question if nobody objects.

Comment: There is no way to delete a bountied question. Can you include more code.. like the parent container of the dropdown?

Comment: @Rob I've added your code in codepen also. That works there. Can you  say where is your issue? https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/rNmvJXo

Comment: I copied the code from JSFiddle and put it in an html file and it works for me. (Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Hi all. As I've said, I've been unable to recreate the issue in a jsfiddle (I made a second one that was pretty much a recreation of the whole page and that worked too).

I have got around the problem in a different way and unfortunately won't be dedicating any more time to solving it. If I could delete the question/bounty, I would.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I created from the fiddle and it works for me. Do you have something differently?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .formatToolbar {
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 900px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 99;
        color: white;
        background-color: #42469D;
        border-radius: 40px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
      }
      
      .formatToolbarIconOuter {
        margin: 12px ;
        color: white ;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-align: center;
        flex: 0 1 auto;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="formatToolbar">
          <div class="formatToolbarIconOuter">
            <span class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="fullColourCodeDropdown">
              <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
              <div class="formatToolbarIconLabel">
                Full seat <br />colour coding
              </div>
            </span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="fullColourCodeDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-25">
      Another div
      <hr>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still see the problem, I think the parent element has an absolute position. Remove it from the element and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You code should have worked.  The only reason to see the issue you describe is if the `z-index` of the "underneath" items are of a z-index greater than the BS default (this should be 1000).

Either lower the z-index of the "underneath" items, or increase the `.dropdown-toggle` z-index with a CSS override, e.g.;

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  z-index: 90000;
}
```